# Compute integral of abs(x-y) with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to compute the integral of 1 - abs(x - y) from -10 to 10 with sympy. I set up the following code snippet:

```py
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import x, y

x = sym.Symbol('x')
y = sym.Symbol('y')

fu_0 = 1 - sym.cos(x-y)
print(sym.integrate(fu_0, (x, -10, 10)))
fu_1 = 1 - sym.Abs(x-y)
print(sym.integrate(fu_1, (x, -10, 10)))
```

The output looks as follows:

```
sin(y - 10) - sin(y + 10) + 20
Integral(1 - Abs(x - y), (x, -10, 10))
```

Apparently, sympy has issues to solve the integral of the desired function `fu_1`. Has anyone an idea what's going wrong here? Issues with sympy and `sympy.Abs` have been fixed a while ago here https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/13930.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pull request you linked provides a bit of clarity about when SymPy is able to rewrite an absolute value as a piecewise. The free symbols must be real.

```
x = sym.Symbol('x', real=True)
y = sym.Symbol('y', real=True)

fu_0 = 1 - sym.cos(x-y)
print(sym.integrate(fu_0, (x, -10, 10)))
# sin(y - 10) - sin(y + 10) + 20
fu_1 = 1 - sym.Abs(x-y)
print(sym.integrate(fu_1, (x, -10, 10)))
# (1 - y)*Min(10, Max(-10, y)) - (y + 1)*Min(10, Max(-10, y)) + Min(10, Max(-10, y))**2 - 80
```

Comment: Seems to work. Amazing, thanks!